# Using string module to loop, and print a message if the translate method works

Tags: python

I am not too sure if I worded the title correctly but what I am attempting to do is if the while loop detects that the `new_string` did indeed remove punctuation to print that it was invalid, I am sure how I have it set-up now even if it did work correctly it would print invalid twice.

Any recommendations, or if I can even get this to work correctly using the string module.

```
import string


def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    exclusions(plate)
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def exclusions(s):
    new_string = s.translate(
        str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    while len(new_string) < is_valid(s):
        if new_string == True:
            print("Invalid\nPlease do not use punctuation")
    print(new_string)


def is_valid(s):
    return 2 <= len(s) <= 6


main()
```

I know I would have to call back into the main function for it to print invalid, somehow just not sure how.

I was hoping this would be a "faster" more efficient way instead of creating a list with all the punctuations then a million if statements.

Comment: Could not understand exactly what is the logical error you are trying to explain!
Also, this `if new_string == True:` will never be true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go and turn

```
    while len(new_string) < is_valid(s):
        if new_string == True:
            print("Invalid\nPlease do not use punctuation")
```

to

```
    if len(new_string) < len(s):
        print("Please do not use punctuation")
        print(new_string)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So, full code is

```
import string


def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    return_val = exclusions(plate)

    if return_val:
        print("Invalid")
    else:
        print("Valid")


def exclusions(s):
    new_string = s.translate(
        str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    if len(new_string) < len(s):
        print("Please do not use punctuation")
        print(new_string)
        return True
    else:
        return False


main()
```

which should print if there were and punctuations, assuming they were stripped from translate

Comment: Okay yes that does work, but it also prints valid, how would I go about having it not running through the other if statement if that statement is true ( It having punctuation )

Comment: Just switch prints and cut out valid, *edited